# R subset data.frame on timestamps

Tags: r, dataframe, timestamp, filtering, posixct

i want to filter my data frame on the timestamp column selecting the row only if the corresponding timestamp is in a list.

```
boxplot_data <- subset(new_data, timestamp %in% selected_timestamps)
```

new_data is a data frame containing the timestamp column (PosixCT type) and selected_timestamps is a vector (i tried also a list) of the same type as timestamp column.
Filtering this way i have only an empty data frame with the same column number.
Any hint?

**Update**
Here is a bit of new_data:

```
 201021 2013-06-11 22:58:39                 19                    10      0.5263158
 201021 2013-06-11 23:03:40                 19                     9      0.4736842
```

the timestamp type is:

```
timestamp            : POSIXct, format: ....
```

And of selected_timestamps:

```
[1] "2013-06-11 09:03:39 CEST" "2013-06-11 10:03:39 CEST" "2013-06-11 11:03:44 CEST"
[4] "2013-06-11 12:03:39 CEST" "2013-06-11 13:03:39 CEST" "2013-06-11 14:03:39 CEST"
[7] "2013-06-11 15:03:39 CEST" "2013-06-11 16:03:40 CEST" "2013-06-11 17:03:39 CEST"
```

the type of selected_timestamps is :

```
POSIXct[1:24], format: ....
```

Comment: It looks as if it should work, so may be a problem with the type or format of the data - can you share a bit of your data `new_data` and `selected_timestamps`?

Comment: I might be wrong, but shouldn't it be `new_data$timestamp`? That's how it would be if you were subsetting using `[`

Answer (score 0):

I expect the problem to be due to timestamp column in your data.frame to have a differnt timezone attribute. Subsetting works fine when the time zone are identical, see code below:

```
x <- as.POSIXct(c("2013-06-11 22:58:39", "2013-06-11 22:58:40", "2013-06-11 22:58:41", "2013-06-11 22:58:42"))
y <- as.POSIXct(c("2013-06-11 22:58:40", "2013-06-11 22:58:41"))

df <- data.frame(timestamp = x)
print(df)
subset(df, timestamp %in% y)

df$timestamp[[2]]
y[1]
```

Output:

```
> print(df)
            timestamp
1 2013-06-11 22:58:39
2 2013-06-11 22:58:40
3 2013-06-11 22:58:41
4 2013-06-11 22:58:42
> subset(df, timestamp %in% y)
            timestamp
2 2013-06-11 22:58:40
3 2013-06-11 22:58:41
> df$timestamp[[2]]
[1] "2013-06-11 22:58:40 CEST"
> y[1]
[1] "2013-06-11 22:58:40 CEST"
```

I suggest you check the timezone by `print(new_data$timestamp[1])`.